# How to get Azure PID (Object ID) which is related to given Application ID

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-api-apps, azure-rest-api

When I try to retrieve pole assignments it gives values which is related to a Principle ID. But currently I have only the tenant id, client id and the client secret. So is there any way to retrieve Principle IDs ?

[image]

Comment: Are you looking to find service principal id?

Answer (score 0):

Principal ID is the aplication id which is shown in the properties. In this case it should be what is shown in the 2nd row (Application ID)